# Adjust the caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

As you know that the caption can `\flushright` or `\flushleft` by this command

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
```

Right now I want to make the **caption of figure is in center** and **caption of table is in the right** in the same paper. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\captionsetup[<type>]{<options>}` macro takes an optional argument for specifying the float `<type>` that should have their settings changed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,showframe}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft, singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[t]
  \caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

Some text.

\end{document}
```